# How did Hindu scholars determine that North America is Kraunchadvipa?

Tags: rituals, puja, geography, sankalpa

According to the Hindu scriptures, there are 7 continents or dvipas named:

- Jambu ("Indian Blackberry tree")
- Plaksha ("Ficus religiosa (Peepal) tree")
- Shalmali ("Bombax tree")
- Kusha ("grass")
- Kraunca ("Mountain")
- Shaka ("Pine tree")
- Pushkara ("Maple tree")

Each continent is surrounded by a particular liquid. Jambudvipa is surrounded by an ocean of salt water. Kraunchadvipa is surrounded by an ocean of milk.

> Krauñcadvīpa is surrounded by an ocean of milk as broad as the island
>   itself - Bhagavata Purana

Hindu priests and scholars have determined that the North American continent is Kraunchadvipa. Before poojas, temple priests recite a "sankalpa", announcing the time, location, yuga, etc of the pooja or yajna they are about to perform. In India they say "Jambudvipe, bharata varshe", etc. In the US, they say "Kraunchadvipe, ramanakavarshe", etc.

My question is, how did they determine that North America is Kraunchadvipa? This continent is not surrounded by an ocean of milk. It is surrounded by salt water just like Jambudvipa.

Comment: i think it may mean that color of ocean water is milky...

Comment: @YDS I doubt it. They would say "like milky" and not "made of milk".

Comment: The Sanskrit words would be क्षीरोद, घृतोद etc...and according to the Sanskrit dictionary, along with 'ocean of Ghee', one meaning of घृतोद would be 'ocean of ghee-water or water resembling ghee'... similarly क्षीरोद would mean 'ocean of kshir-water or water resembling kshir (milk) or milky water..

Comment: This is not an off-topic question or scientific speculation question. In a sankalpa which performing pooja, we say in which place we are performing pooja. In that, we say "Jamboo Dweepe" or "Krauncha Dweepe" based on location. Asking why it is called so isn't off-topic. From [help/on-topic], "Questions about Hindu practices." Sankalpam is a Hindu practice.Close-voters,please read help center before voting to close.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How did ancient Hindu scholars interpret the continent theory of Hindu scripture?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/35969/how-did-ancient-hindu-scholars-interpret-the-continent-theory-of-hindu-scripture)

Comment: Hindu priests and scholars went by their natural instincts instead of logical reasoning and hence valid points raised by you in your question got ignored.

Comment: according to surya siddhanta, entire northern hemisphere is jambudvipa with north pole as mount meru. Thus US will be roughly uttara kuru. This can also be confirmed from harivamsa.